# OneToMany PersistentBag

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a problem with storing OneToMany relationship with Hibernate.

What I got is AdvertisementData entity which looks as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "advertisement_data")
public class AdvertisementData {

@Id
@Column(name = "order_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
@GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "order"))
private Long id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, mappedBy = "advertisementData")
private List<KRPData> krpData;

//setters and getters
}
```

and KRPData which is defined as follows:

```
@Entity
public class KRPData {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String description;

@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.SerializableToBlobType")
private List<String> images;

private String section;

@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.SerializableToBlobType")
private List<String> filenames;

@ManyToOne
private AdvertisementData advertisementData;

//getters and setters
}
```

I can see that both entities are stored, however every time I fetch AdvertisementData, the results looks like:

[image]

KRPData is returned as PersistentBag without any data.

Hibernate version: 4.2.2.Final

Any ideas what could be the case?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: When are you trying to access the list with respect to your database transaction?  Please post the accessor code

Comment: Where is the @JoinColumn? Is the convention being satisfied?

Comment: Solved! Entities were saved in wrong order, hence KRPData didn't had information about AdvertisementData id and columns were not joined. Thanks for Your comments!